# WebJob taking too long to connect into the Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a WebJob inside my App Service, actually I'm running it manually.
The WebJob are a console .NET CORE application, the main goal of this console app are update a database table with events.

Running locally I don't have any issue (pointing for the same DB), but when I run it inside the Azure it takes more than 1 hour just to connect with the database and then make the processment that I want.

This is what happen when I start the WebJob:

```
[04/12/2017 23:27:05 > xpto55: INFO] Connecting Database...
[04/13/2017 00:55:56 > xpto55: INFO] Database connected
[04/13/2017 00:58:21 > xpto55: INFO] Generating events...
```

I'm using Migrations and Entity Framework Core.

Who can I improve my performance? Which kind of log can I make to mitigate this problem?

Comment: Not much in the way of detail here. There seems to be quite a few other people that have solved this issue...https://www.google.com/search?q=azure+connection+slow&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the default Connection String:

```
Server=tcp:db.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=catalog;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=???;Password=???;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Pooling=False;
```

Changing it to:

```
Data Source=db.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=catalog;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=???;Password=???;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Min Pool Size=3;Load Balance Timeout=180;
```

Solved my problem. Mainly change the `Poll Size`.